# How to copy and execute a file using Active Directory to a client?

Tags: c#, active-directory, copy, task

I want to update my software on a domain. How can I copy and execute my updates using Active Directory to users' systems ?

*other case*: Is it possible install **MSI** setup file using Active Directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use Login scripts or GPOs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779329%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to deploy Software, but a Software deployment System is of course better...

If you have MSIs (and optionaly transforms and patches) you can easily [publish them in a GPO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102/en-us). Watch a Video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRNCgvZs5v4).